# can't kill process by Ctrl-c in a boost.python module with an endless loop

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I have make a boost.python module with an endless loop.But I can't kill the process by ctrl-c.The following is an example.

C++

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python.module.hpp>
#include <boost/python.def.hpp>
#include <iostream>
usring namespace boost::python;

void foo() {
   int it=0;
   while (true) {                     //endless loop
       ++it;
       std::cout<< it <<std::endl;
       sleep(3);
   }
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(ctopy)
{
    def("foo",foo);
}
```

python:

```
import ctopy
ctopy.foo()
```

result:

```
1
2
3
4
.....................
```

I can't kill the foreground process by Ctrl-c.why the module don't accept signal "SIGINT" that was sent by Ctrl-c.How to make it work.

Comment: OS ? did you have already tried with CTRL+D ?

Comment: centos6.0,I have tried Ctrl+D.@user1849534

Comment: `ps aux` to get the PID of the process and `kill -9` it?

Comment: I have not try "kill -9",I believe it will work.But I want to make "Ctrl-c" work.@inspectorG4dget

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should call [PyErr_CheckSignals()](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_CheckSignals) periodically in your extension code and call `exit()` if it returns `-1`:

```cpp
while (true) { //endless loop
    ++it;
    std::cout<< it <<std::endl;
    sleep(3);
    if(PyErr_CheckSignals() == -1) {
        exit(1);
    }
  }
```